# can't get input error box to show up Red color c# WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm getting error on Principal (int.TryParse(txtprincipal.Text, out **principal**("C"))). I want user to correctly put Amount as input box and if it's blank of wrong input textbox should show up as red color.
Can anyone tell me where I'm making mistake?

Comment: this may help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.borderthickness(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please post working code including your XAML. I tested this and it works fine. Also keep in mind that if you use proper MVVM, you could get the same effect more easily with binding validations.

Comment: Here is my XAML code

 <Label x:Name="lblprincipal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Principal Amount:" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14.667" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,6,6,9" Width="136" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="26"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtprincipal" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="184" FontFamily="Gadugi" FontSize="14.667" BorderThickness="1.5" Margin="10,6,0,7" ToolTip="Pricipal"/>

Comment: I'm not sure how to do Binding.  I'm new at c# coding.

Comment: You should spend some time to read WPF binding, it fairly simple work with binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `principal` is declared as `double principal;` that means that of type `double` and you are using `int.TryParse()` to extract a double value from the input text. That leads to the error, use [`Double.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. which will

> Converts the string representation of a number to its double-precision
>   floating-point number equivalent. A return value indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded or failed.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtprincipal.Text) || !Double.TryParse(txtprincipal.Text, out principal)
{
   // Code here
}
```

You can use [`style, culture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx) for confirming the format of the outcome.